# Run svn info & findstr in powershell then save to variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file, svn, cmd

How can we run the following batch script statement (or something in those lines) in a powershell script and save output to a variable.
We don't necessarily have to use cmd/batch commands, equivalent powershell commands will do.

```
svn info --xml pathToRepo\product | findstr /v ^<^?
```

Probably something like

```
$svnInfoOutput = svn info --xml pathToRepo\product | findstr /v ^<^? | Out-Null
```

So now displaying $svnInfoOutput should show:

```
<info>
<entry
   kind="dir"
   path="path"
   revision="647524">
<url>http://url</url>
<relative-url>^/url</relative-url>
<repository>
<root>http://urlroot</root>
<uuid>593eaae0-013a-</uuid>
</repository>
<wc-info>
<wcroot-abspath>absPath</wcroot-abspath>
<schedule>normal</schedule>
<depth>infinity</depth>
</wc-info>
<commit
   revision="6297">
<author>zz</author>
<date>2014-12-15T09:21:29.369584Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</info>
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do with this? PowerShell can parse XML into objects on its own, there's no need to treat it as text.

Comment: If you do svn info on a folder (which has been checked out from svn repo), it starts with < ? xml element. I am trying get the < info > only and remove the xml one.

Comment: See my answer. Treat XML as the objects it can represent, not as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[xml]$svnInfoOutput = svn info --xml pathToRepo\product
```

`$svnInfoOutput` is now an object and you can treat it like any other, looking at the properties (including attributes) of each node.

`$svnInfoOutput.info.entry` will give you a formatted list describing both the attributes and node contents of the `entry` node in the XML above. You can futher interrogate these values with `$svnInfoOutput.info.entry.revision` to get the revision number (for example).

Comment: This is interesting! Didn't know this. 
@venkhatapriya's answer works for me in this scope, but this one is more elegant.
May I ask a bit more than the original question:
I am using the string value to be an element in a separate xml. Can we do so using you approach? Similar to:
$xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("ComponentSvnInfo", $svnInfoOutput.info)
with output file as
<ComponentSvnInfo><Info> .....</info></ComponentSvnInfo>

Comment: You may be able to; I've never tried it. Give it a shot and find out! You might have to use one of the other `XMLDocument` methods to get the whole node including tags.

Comment: I think this method is clean and makes sense, hence marked as answer. Thanks.
Apologies for the delay in selecting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Select-String for any match/non Match: `Select-String -NotMatch '<?xml'`

To pass output of a command into a variable easiest approach is to use `2>&1`

So combining them together should get the output you are looking for:

```
$svnInfoOutput = svn info --xml pathToRepo\product | Select-String -NotMatch '<?xml' 2>&1
```